# Sinatra method `development?` undefined

Tags: ruby, sinatra

The Sinatra docs say that `development?` will return true when the environment is development, but I receive an error stating that the method `development?` is undefined.

I tried skipping the shorthand and testing the `ENV['RAKE_ENV']` variable itself, but it was just nil.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
undefined method `development?' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

and this is the code that is triggering the error:

```
require 'dm-sqlite-adapter' if development?
```

I am using the modular style app. The line above is an separate file that only manages the model. What's going on?

Comment: What happens if you use it as a symbol (with a colon character) require "xyz" if :development?

Comment: Fixed it. Many thanks. If you want to put it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it as correct. What is the difference between symbol and non-symbol syntax? How do I know when to use which?

Comment: @EmanueleFeliziani that isn’t a fix `... if :any_symbol_whatsoever` will always return true, as a symbol is not `nil` or `false`.

Comment: Yep @matt, you're right. Any clue as to what could be causing the issue, then?

Comment: `require 'dm-sqlite-adapter' if Sinatra::Base.environment == :development` will do the job.

Comment: Thank you Arup. Tested both locally and on Heroku and this solution seems to work. Can you please explain to me why the simple `development?` method was not working? Is it because it's a modular-style app? Again, if you want to post this as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled with this one, too. Here's what I discovered along the way.

You need to be "inside" a class that inherits from Sinatra::Base (such as Sinatra::Application, which inherits from Base) to be able to use the  `development?` method, which is defined in [base.rb](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb).

In a classic Sinatra app you are already coding "inside" a class that inherits from Sinatra::Base. So `development?` will just work "anywhere".

In modular Sinatra the `development?` will only work in Sinatra::Base sub-classes, such as:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

# Placing
# require 'dm-sqlite-adapter' if development?
# here will not work.

class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
require 'dm-sqlite-adapter' if development? # But here it works
...
end

# Placing 
# require 'dm-sqlite-adapter' if development?` 
# AFTER the above class will still not work

class SomethingElse 
# nor will `development?` work here, since it is called inside
# a class without Sinatra::Base inheritance
...
end
```

So basically you can use an ApplicationController class that inherits from Sinatra::Base and inside here check for `development?`. The same goes for sub-classes that inherits from your ApplicationController class:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  require 'dotenv' if development?
  ...
end
```

For modular Sinatra, in the (main:Object) code text "outside" Sinatra::Base sub-classes, you need to follow [Arup's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit) instructions:

```
if Sinatra::Base.environment == :development
    require 'awesome_print'
    require 'dotenv'
    Dotenv.load
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using the modular style, you need to add the module namespace `Sinatra::Base` before the method.

So you will be able to access `Sinatra::Base.development?` anywhere in the app.